# Change state of parent component in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change a value in the parent component by changing the state in the child component which is passed by props.

```js
// This is the parent component
const [showEdit, setShowEdit] = useState(false);
<EditApplicationSettings
  appSettings={appSettings}
  changeState={(showEdit) => setShowEdit(showEdit)}
/>

// This is the child component
export default function EditApplicationSettings({ appSettings, props }) {
  return (
    <button
      className="button-red"
      onClick={() => props.changeState(false)}
    >
      Cancel
    </button>
  );
}
```

When I click on the button, that **should change the state in parent**, but instead, I get an **error**.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changeState')
```

Where did I do wrong in passing the props?

Comment: **It's basically a typo.** You have `{appSettings, props}` in the parameter list of the child where you mean to have `{appSettings, changeState}` (and then just use `changeState`, not `props.changeState`, in the `onClick`). You're passing the component `appSettings` and `changeState` props, not `appSettings` and `props` props.

Comment: The issue and solution are provided in the above comment. Adding to that fixed example here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-gdng0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React terms `props` tends to refer to the entire property object:

```
EditApplicationSettings(props)
```

But since you're [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the properties from the object you need to reference the `changeState` property explicitly:

```
EditApplicationSettings({ appSettings, changeState })
```

and

```
onClick={() => changeState(false)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Missed that one!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changeState')
```

then this line

```
export default function EditApplicationSettings({ appSettings, props }) {
```

should be

```
export default function EditApplicationSettings({ appSettings, ...props }) {
                                                               ^^^
```

You could read more at [MDN doc for destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)